# LiPo battery sparks when used with DC step up convertor

Tags: batteries, lipo, buck-boost

I'm using a LiPo battery 700mAh 3.7V with MT3608 DC-DC step up boost converter module 2V-24V 2A.

The problem is when I connect these to anything or even the wires just touch each other they produce a spark. I want to hide or remove them so that it doesn't harm my ESP32. Also is there any way with which I can reduce the current of the output from the battery?

Comment: Comments for this conversation have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115057/discussion-on-question-by-animesh-lipo-battery-sparks-when-used-with-dc-step-up).